# Making a different type of home page in Orchard

Tags: model-view-controller, orchardcms

I've just started with the Orchard CMS and I can see that I can create a page and have different widgets on them, but I need the homepage to have a different layout.

I'd like to have some sort of different cshtml file for the homepage, but I can't seem to work out how to do it from the documentation. I also need to have four text areas on the home page that aren't on the main page.

Can someone who has done this point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you, it's a post I found about making your own themes and is a fairly simple example but covers what you are looking for:

http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/theming-orchard

> /Views/Content-11.cshtml
>
> I wanted to display the content on my
>   homepage slightly differently than
>   other pages. My homepage has an ID of
>   11 so I was able to reference it with
>   a file called Content-11.cshtml. I
>   could also have created a template for
>   all blog post content using a file
>   called Content-BlogPost.cshtml had I
>   needed to do so.

Comment: That's a good enough solution for what I need. When I have the luxury of time, I'll research if there's a way to do a "page of type..." link to a theme.

Answer (score 1):

You should use designer tools module if you are using Orchard 1.1 +. Just search for Shapes in the admin and install the tools. Then you can create Alternates by reviewing the shapes in-browser.

In your case you should be able to create a view with the name: Content-url-homepage.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to vary the homepage layout: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/12/14/switching-the-layout-in-orchard-cms.aspx

Orchard 1.1 will also give you a homepage alternate out of the box.